# Crawling output into a csv file with colums

Tags: python, csv

I would like to know how to export my results from crawling into a csv file with different columns

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}

output_file= open("City.csv", "w")

r = requests.get("http://www.bla/paris/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "itemsContent clearafter"})
for item in g_data:
    Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
    Header_final = (Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())
    price = item.find_all("div", {"class": "prodPrice"})
    Price_final = (price[0].contents[0].text.strip())
    Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
    for t in Deeplink:
        Deeplink_final = (t.get("href"))

    print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "Price: " + Price_final + " |  " + "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final)
    output_file.write("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "Price: " + Price_final + " | " + "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final + "\n")
```

I´m able to put my data into a csv file but not sure how to create 3 dedicated columns for it.
"Header: " + Header_final should be the first column. "Price: " + Price_final the second one. And "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final my last one.

Could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the csv module. You import it, but don't use it. You can find documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

Before the for loop add the following to create a csv writer and write the header line:

```
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
csv_fields = ['Header', 'Price', 'Deeplink']
if gdata:
    writer.writerow(csv_fields)
```

Then in the body of the loop, replace your write statement with this:

```
writer.writerow([Header_final, Price_final, Deeplink_final])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Appreciate it:) Works now